# Can we plot the inverse Laplace transform of the function $(x+1/2)^{x-1/2}$?

Tags: graphing-functions, laplace-transform

I understand that there is possibly no closed form, but can one somehow plot it using, say, Mathematica?

Comment: There is a Mathematica stack exchange, which is where this question belongs (after tightening it up to be a more direct question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Mathematica can do this kind of thing. Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

For completeness I'll paste the command I used:

```
Plot[Log[InverseLaplaceTransform[(x + 1/2)^(x - 1/2), x, t]], {t, -10,
   10}]
```

Answering followup questions from the comments:

1. To see why I wrapped it in Log before plotting, just look at the graph I got! If the log-scaled version is shooting off to 1000+ then the non-logscale version will grow obscenely fast and won't make a very pretty graph to look at.
2. It took 414 seconds on my laptop.
3. Actually I'm pretty sure it has an asymptote at $x=0$. You could test where the inverse transform is defined just by plugging in individual points like `InverseLaplaceTransform[(x + 1/2)^(x - 1/2), x, 0.000001]` and `InverseLaplaceTransform[(x + 1/2)^(x - 1/2), x, -0.000001]`.

Comment: I tried without Log but it did not work for some reason.

Comment: How long should it take?

Comment: I wonder also, whether it has an asymptote `x=1`?

Comment: I edited my answer to address these followup questions too.